# Working with sqlite and codeigniter

Tags: php, sqlite, codeigniter

My goal is to create a sqlite database file that would be downloaded by iOS application later.

My question is, how can i create a sqlite database file with CodeIgniter? What is the sqlite file's structure?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `SQLite3` classes to create a new database in "native" PHP, this is nothing to do with CodeIgniter!

```
$db = new SQLite3("todownload.db");
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE whatever ( whatever INT )");
```

Comment: great! i've never heard about that class.